# VideoView on Archos 5 (Android 1.6) doesn't work

Tags: android, android-videoview, archos

I'm developing an app for the Archos 5 Internet Tablet. (With Android 1.6)

I want to start a video in a VideoView within my app. On my Android emulator the following code works fine but on my Archos 5 I always get an error:

Cannot play video

Sorry, this video cannot be played.

```
//get current window information, and set format, set it up differently, if you need some special effects
getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

//the VideoView will hold the video
VideoView videoHolder = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView01);
//MediaController is the ui control hovering above the video (just like in the default youtube player).
videoHolder.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
//assing a video file to the video holder
videoHolder.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://mypackage/" + R.raw.testmovie));
//get focus, before playing the video.
videoHolder.requestFocus();
if(autoplay){
    videoHolder.start();
}
```

Is there a way to run a VideoView on a archos 5?

I also tried to play the movie with the archos player. With the following code I get the error: "Cannot find the media file!".

```
    String ACTION_LAUNCH_AVOS = "android.intent.action.LAUNCH_AVOS"; 
    String avosCommand = "ACTION:video_play,url=videoentries:Video/testmovie.wmv,etype=resume";

    final Intent startAvos = new Intent(ACTION_LAUNCH_AVOS,Uri.parse(avosCommand));

    startAvos.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
    startActivity(startAvos);
```

I put the video in the Video folder of the Archos. The video runs when I open it with the file browser.

I always get the error "Cannot find the media file!", no matter what url I use.

Is there a certain folder where I have to put the video so that it can be found? And how do I get the url to that certain folder?

It would be great if you could help me!

Thanks and BR,
Thomas